# Backwards Propagation: are analytical second derivatives worth calculating?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mathematical-optimization, hessian-matrix

I understand the reason why we typically do not use second derivative information is that the Hessian can be very large with more layers and weights, leading to high computational expense, so Hessian-free methods are preferred. My question is **whether the computational expense that the literature refers to is a result of the assumption that second derivatives are being calculated numerically**? So if instead the objective function under evaluation gave rise to neat analytical second derivatives, then could a Newton based method be computationally tractable for estimating ANN parameters even with a large number of hidden layers? Or is it purely the size of the Hessian - and the need/expense to invert it for the updating algorithm (!) - that is the determining factor for using gradient based methods instead?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use 2nd order optimization methods, you should calculate **inverse** of the Hessian matrix. There are 2 problems with that:

1. The Hessian has O(N<sup>2</sup>) parameters, which makes it harder to compute (both in terms of memory and time complexity). Even if you calculate each one in O(1) time (that is, you compute derivatives using an analytic formula), you still need to compute quadratic amount of them.
2. Matrix inversion is [quite slow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) operation, which takes even more time (O(N<sup>3</sup> in case of Gaussian Elimination), for example, in case of ) than just calculating all the values of the Hessian.